Sqlalchemy keep encrypting while keep field unique
Which I want a value been encrypted when commit to table. Then query with clear text.
I read the sqlalchemey wiki. By using typedecorator, it worked well.
However, how to keep clear text unique giver that for the same text, encrypted value differs?
The code segment as follows:
class EncryptedValue(TypeDecorator):
    impl = String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return aes_encrypt(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return aes_decrypt(value)


Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column("encrypted_value", EncryptedValue(40), unique=True)

Make sure unique value been encrypted when write into table.

Are you targetting a particular RDBMS?
